# How do I replace and add specific numbers in a string in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently trying to clean a column of data, which contains the phone numbers of users. The phone numbers are not consistent in their format and need to be standardised.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name': ['John', 'Dom', 'Jack', 'Sam', 'Fred', 'Harvey', 'Toby'],
        'Phone': ['+49(0) 047905356', '(0161) 496 0674', '239.711.3836', '02984 08192', 
        '(0306) 999 0871', '0121x496x0225', '+44047905356']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now I've tried to use the following code to remove the special characters:

```
df['Phone'] = df['Phone'].replace('\W','', regex=True)
```

This works, however, I want to replace the numbers that only contain a + sign followed by the code with '0' to achieve the following:

Example of expected outputs:

Input: `'+49(0) 047905356'` | Expected: `'047905356'`

Input: `'+44047905356'`| Expected: `'047905356'`

But then I also want **numbers without a '0' at the beginning to include one**, for example:

Input: `'239.711.3836'` | Expected: `'02397113836'`

Comment: Please can you provide the full expected output?

Comment: For your second example, how are you supposed to know to separate the `44` from the `047905356`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use requlare expression to achieve the desired result.

```
import re

import pandas as pd 
data = {'Name': ['John', 'Dom', 'Jack', 'Sam', 'Fred', 'Harvey', 'Toby'],
'Phone': ['+49(0) 047905356', '(0161) 496 0674', '239.711.3836', '02984 08192',
'(0306) 999 0871', '0121x496x0225', '+44047905356']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

data = {'Name': ['John', 'Dom', 'Jack', 'Sam', 'Fred', 'Harvey', 'Toby'],
        'Phone': ['+49(0) 047905356', '(0161) 496 0674', '239.711.3836', '02984 08192', 
        '(0306) 999 0871', '0121x496x0225', '+44047905356']}
df['Phone'] = df['Phone'].replace('\D', '', regex=True)

df.loc[df['Phone'].str.startswith('+'), 'Phone'] = '0' + df['Phone'].str[1:]

df.loc[~df['Phone'].str.startswith('0'), 'Phone'] = '0' + df['Phone']

df['Phone'] = df['Phone'].str[:2] + '.' + df['Phone'].str[2:4] + '.' + df['Phone'].str[4:]
```

Output:

```
     Name            Phone
0    John  04.90.047905356
1     Dom    01.61.4960674
2    Jack    02.39.7113836
3     Sam     02.98.408192
4    Fred    03.06.9990871
5  Harvey    01.21.4960225
6    Toby   04.40.47905356
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have only numbers in your Phone column, you could use the regex `[^0-9]`.

You can know if a string starts with 0 using `str.startswith()`

```
df['Phone'] = df['Phone'].replace('[^0-9]','', regex=True)

df['start_with_0'] = df.Phone.str.startswith("0")
df['needs_0'] = df.start_with_0.replace({True:"", False:"0"})
df['Phone_new'] =  df.needs_0 + df.Phone
df
```